# how to get UITextView value to send in app mail?

Tags: ios, objective-c, email

I'm using this code to display a `UITextView` and a `UIButton` but now I need to get the text inside `UITextView` and, on the button click, open the mail composer with my `UITextView` text already written in an email message.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    UITextField *textnome = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 55, 290, 40)];
    textnome.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
    textnome.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];
    textnome.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
    textnome.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
    textnome.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
    textnome.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
    textnome.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:textnome];

    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [button addTarget:self
               action:@selector(emailButton:)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [button setTitle:@"Enviar" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 840, 320, 40);
    [self.view addSubview:button];

    [self.scrollView addSubview:button];
    [self.scrollView addSubview:textnome];
}

- (IBAction)emailButton:(id)sender {

    MFMailComposeViewController *mailController = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc]init];
    [mailController setMailComposeDelegate:self];
    NSString *email = @"decco.santos@hotmail.com";
    NSArray *emailArray = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:email, nil];
    NSString *message = [[self HERE I NEED TO DEFINE UITEXTVIEW VALUE BUT IT`S NOT WORKING WHEN I USE textnome]text];
    [mailController setMessageBody:message isHTML:NO];
    [mailController setToRecipients:emailArray];
    [mailController setSubject:@"Noticia RSSAdv"];
    [self presentViewController:mailController animated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [[self textnome] resignFirstResponder];
}

-(void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

I do not declare `textnome` in the .h file because I don't know how to link .m to .h programmatically.

Comment: Declare `textnome` globally

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a property for this in your .m file (or .h. file). If you declare it in the .m file, it can be used only in the .m file itself. If you declare in in the .h file it can also be accessed from other classes. I'l assume you just want to access it in your .m file.

Like this

```
@interface YourControllerName ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) UITextField *textnome;
@end
```

You need to place this code right after your imports in the .m file. Do not forget to adjust YourControllerName to the name of your controller.

Then this piece of code needs to be changed to this:

```
self.textnome = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 55, 290, 40)];
self.textnome.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
self.textnome.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];
self.textnome.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
self.textnome.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
self.textnome.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
self.textnome.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
self.textnome.delegate = self;
[self.view addSubview:self.textnome];
```

This way your have a reference to the textnome property throughout the rest of your class.

Then read out it's value by using the text property on the textNome:

```
NSString *message = self.textnome.text;
```

Answer (score 0):

Option #1: (.m declaration)

If you want to limit your variable's scope so it's privately available in the .m, Edwardmp's answer is one correct way to do this. As he states in his answer, adding the property definition to a class extension at the top of the .m would in fact work:

```
@interface YourControllerName ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) UITextField *textnome;
@end

@implementation YourControllerName

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    self.textnome = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 55, 290, 40)];
```

And generally speaking, if you don't need the instance variable to be public, it's generally best practice to place the variable as a private property definition in this section of the .m code.

Option #2: (.h declaration)

Otherwise, to "link" the .m and .h as you describe and thus potentially give yourself the ability to publicly access the variable from other classes, declare the variable as a `@property` below the `@interface` block in your .h:

```
@interface YourControllerName : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) UITextField *textnome;
```

Then throughout the .m, just like in option #1, you can access `textnome` using `self.textnome`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    self.textnome = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 55, 290, 40)];
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to post textview text in mail you only need the following line code in mail controller

```
[mailController setMessageBody:Textview.text isHTML:NO];
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all... The OP knows this since this line's already in his code, but his problem is that he doesn't know how to access the text in the textfield since it's a local variable.